# Move Content Down on Mobile Phones

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to move a column of content down on mobile phones (no tablets), but can't figure it out. The end goal is to move the custom field data below the body text.

Via:http://beta.johnslanding.org/portland/canyon-hoops/

```
.one-fourth.last.right
```

**Tried this:**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 400px) {
-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
-o-column-break-inside:avoid;
-ms-column-break-inside:avoid;
column-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

You'll see on my iPhone the theme keeps these two columns together:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is moving `div.three-fourths` (your body content) above `div.one-fourth` (the sidebar content) in your HTML, so something like this:

```
<div class="three-fourths">...</div>
<div class="one-fourth last right">...</div>
```

Because your content area has a `float:left` and your sidebar has a `float:right`  with exact width's set, rearranging the HTML will have no effect to the way it looks, only the order of the HTML.

And, then clear the floats and set new widths to fill the viewport under your desired resolution. This will ensure it tucks under the body content under 480px screens.

```
@media (max-width:30em){
  .three-fourths,
  .one-fourth.last.right{
    float:none;
    width:100%
  }
}
```